php failed to call curl command
I want to get the data from a curl command in php for further processing.
I am facing an issue with the code when I use it in php. The curl command looks good for me when I run it in the system.
My code is as follows:
<?php

function getJsonFromUrl($urlString) {
    $urlData = shell_exec('curl --silent --request GET --url \'' . $urlString . '\' --user \'root:password\' --header \'Accept: application/json\'');
    $jsonData = json_decode($urlData, true);
    return $jsonData;
}

$data = array(
    'id' => '',
    'parent' => '',
    'issueId' => '1931461',
    'issueType' => ''
);

$url = "https://jira.myorg.com/rest/dev-status/1.0/issue/detail?issueId={$data['issueId']}&applicationType=stash&dataType=repository";
$jsonData = getJsonFromUrl($url);
?>

I am getting the following errors:

'applicationType' is not recognized as an internal or external
command,
operable program or batch file.
'dataType' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Deprecated: json_decode(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($json) of
type string is deprecated in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\test.php
on line 4

Please help me with it

Why don't you just use the curl functions built directly into PHP instead of trying to run a shell command? https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

function getJsonFromUrl($urlString) {
$ch= curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlString);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "root:password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json',
'content-type: application/json'));
$urlData = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return json_decode($urlData);
}

facing error   tack trace: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
#0 {main}
thrown in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\test.php on line for line echo getJsonFromUrl($urlString)

Hi. As you can see, it's quite hard to read the code when it's placed in the comments like this. Stackoverflow isn't like a standard discussion forum (see the [tour] for more info). Comments are only used for brief clarification. Your question has an [edit] button under it, which you can use to improve the main post, then the information is visible, all in one place, and can be formatted properly. To allow us to consider your code fully, please edit your question and place it there. How do I format my posts? may be useful to read as well. Thankyou.

But anyway, return json_decode($urlData); returns an object. You cannot echo an object - it has no default or direct textual representation, so PHP cannot simply output it. What exact result were you expecting to get from that echo command? Presumably you'll actually want to echo some specific thing from within the object - e.g. one or more of its proprerties, perhaps? See How can I access an array/object? for details on how to do that in PHP
